# What's the Java equivalent of this declaration in Flex

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript

```
[Embed("assets/BorderContainer.png")]
public const BorderContainerIcon:Class;
```

The xml string of my application menu is formed entirely in java and I can't the iconField="@icon" property of the menuBar component otherwise. It has to be there.

EDIT: I'm shamefully sorry for that phrasing.

Comment: Wait, which language are you looking for, AS or Java? Because that is definitely anything but Java.

Comment: The question is not well phrased, since the code you provided is not Java. (I can't tell you the Flex counter part for that declaration in Java, because it's not a Java declaration.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're looking for a way to embed a resource in a Java class.

The Java compiler won't automatically embed resources in a class file.  However, you can package `BorderContainer.png` into a .jar file along with the rest of your program.  A .jar file is the most common way of distributing client-side executable Java programs (fun fact: a .jar file is just a disguised .zip file).  Then you can access `BorderContainer.png` from your class by using `Class.getResourceAsStream("BorderContainer.png")`.